# Asynchronous IO and Threads

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

*This is rather a conceptual question, and I am trying to get my understanding right about how async IO and threads co-exist.*

Many libs/frameworks are said to have a limitation that even if they support async operations, the "other" libs they depend on are still blocking.

For example, Tornado is a famous Python async web framework and networking library. But, when you integrate it with others, you should make sure that those are also async. So, you shouldn't use `redis.py`, for example, with tornado because it is blocking and won't give you the async goodness.

Node.js, on the other hand has the big advantage that everything is asynchronous, and so there's no problem of having to deal with a mixture of async and blocking libs.

Now, my question is: can't we overcome the problem of mixing the async libs and blocking ones with threads? We can just do the blocking calls within separate threads, and then notify the main async loop when the blocking call finishes?

Hence, isn't "wrapping" a blocking call within a thread, and then using some kind of `wait/notify` construct, essentially turning that blocking call into async call?

My understanding of how threads play with async code is still primitive, so please correct any misconceptions I may have about this.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence, isn't "wrapping" a blocking call within a thread, and then using some kind of wait/notify construct, essentially turning that blocking call into async call?

This is exactly what [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/index.html) (the underlying foundation of node.js) is doing for APIs that don't have a non blocking counterpart (such as file system operations).

It is using a [thread pool](http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/threadpool.html) to perform those blocking operations and notifies the main event loop after they are finished:

> libuv provides a threadpool which can be used to run user code and get notified in the loop thread. This thread pool is internally used to run all filesystem operations, as well as getaddrinfo and getnameinfo requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion of wrapping makes it sound much simpler than it is in practice. For languages like python, doing that and creating a separate thread of execution that has callbacks to the parent thread can be difficult to achieve, especially if you're editing an existing codebase that was never intended to be wrapped like this.

I have seen this done with some modules in node.js though. For example, the module [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) does not have asynchronous implementations (*yet* (I believe there are plans to change this)), but by spawning child processes, you can emulate this with callbacks. The particular implementation of this wrap I've seen in action did not provide a noticeable improvement in performance though, so this might be why you don't see this done a lot to libraries that were originally implemented synchronously.

Comment: So that means within an async environment, threads are of no use? Which is to say that an async program always benefits from being single threaded? (ex. Nginx)

Comment: @treecoder I did not say that. Threads are incredibly useful, even in async environments. Node.js processes are _intended_ to run in parallel in order to scale production, but if you try to use threads to change a synchronous process to asynchronous, then you should begin to question the actual benefit of doing that.

Comment: Ok, so synchronous code should not be turned into async with threads. The correct way is to always use epoll/kqueue and family. Am I right? And if so, then in higher level languages like python, we should use things like the new `asyncio` module for this purpose?

Comment: I don't personally know the answer to that as I am not familiar with those functions, but after glancing at [a brief article](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sangjin/2012/12/21/epoll-vs-kqueue.html) I'm inclined to say that epoll might not scale well according to the author. Again, I could be wrong since I'm not familiar.

Comment: For higher level languages, yes, I would encourage the use of existing "asyncify" modules, if you will, since they're good at generalizing a solution to the issue of making conflicting libraries work together. But that is solely for resolving compatibility between libraries, not for improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with threads is each thread consumes a lot of core memory (up to 1 MB) and unlimited parallelism leads to memory exhaustion. Async I/O lets each connection occupy only limited piece of memory and so lets to increase the number of simultaneous connections. The price is restriction for connections/tasks to do blocking operations, otherwise it leads to that memory exhaustion.

So our main goal is to restrict memory consumption for threads' stacks. The way you proposed to use a dedicated threadpool for blocking operations is correct. We can also think of other ways like using single thread pool with counting and limiting the number of concurrent blocking tasks, but they are more complex and hardly more effective.